# Are there any real-world MonoMac apps that were Mac AppStore approved?

Tags: c#, .net, cocoa, xamarin.ios, monomac

*(I do hope my question still fits into [what is allowed to ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions))*

Having successfully developed and deployed iPhone applications using [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch), I was looking for ways to do it for OS X, too.

What I found was [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac) ([also on Github](https://github.com/mono/monomac)) which looks promising to me.

Since most stuff seems to be from 2010/2011 I'm unsure whether this is still up-to-date.

**My questions therefore are:**

- Are there any real-world applications out there that were recently successfully submitted to the Mac OS X AppStore?
- Would you recommend using it for commercial projects nowadays?
- Are there any working alternatives? (beside learning Objective C, which I'm currently doing)

Comment: If you look here: https://github.com/mono/monomac/commits/master, you'll see that there are recent commits to MonoMac.

Comment: Thanks, @RolfBjarneKvinge To be honest, I do not know how to value these commits since I am rather unexperienced with Github. Are these small maintenance commits or can you see from these commits that there is a high activity in the project?